# Using json_encoding on array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to use json_encode on a array before inserting it on database. So my array contains a 9 photo links. The proper way to inserting DB photo links are row by row. But when I try to start insert it. All nine links one row and it keeps going like that. 1 row 9 links, 1 row 9 links. And I don't know  what s the problem.

Here is the code

```
$rota = new \DOMXPath($parser);
        $images = $rota->query("//div[@class='areapageDetail']//div[@class='areapageDetailList_item_img']//img");

        foreach ($images as $image) {
            $photos[] = $image->getAttribute("src");
        }
```

This is the photo url contains array.

and the way I insert is right below.

```
foreach ($outlineUrl as $results) {
        if (strpos($results, 'http://www.daikyo.co.jp/') === 0) {
            $html = file_get_contents($results);
            $DOMParser = new \DOMDocument();
            $DOMParser->loadHTML($html);

            $changeForMyDB = [
                'region' => '関西',
                'photo' => json_encode($photos),
                'link' => json_encode($results),
                'building_name' => '',
                'price' => '',
                'old_price' => '',
                'extend' => '',
                'address' => '',
                'total_house' => '',
                'rooms' => '',
                'cons_finish' => '',
                'entry' => '',
                'balcony' => '',
                'company_name' => '',
            ];
```

This is the part of the code. For example `$results` is array too which is contain web site links. And there is no problem with that. I can insert $results array links row by row. But not photo links. Why is that happening just for the photo links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to index each photo in that case

```
$i = 0;
foreach ($outlineUrl as $results) {
    if (strpos($results, 'http://www.daikyo.co.jp/') === 0) {
        $html = file_get_contents($results);
        $DOMParser = new \DOMDocument();
        $DOMParser->loadHTML($html);

        $changeForMyDB = [
            'region' => '関西',
            'photo' => json_encode($photos[$i]),
            'link' => json_encode($results),
            'building_name' => '',
            'price' => '',
            'old_price' => '',
            'extend' => '',
            'address' => '',
            'total_house' => '',
            'rooms' => '',
            'cons_finish' => '',
            'entry' => '',
            'balcony' => '',
            'company_name' => '',
        ];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

you also have to make sure that photos count matches your outlineurl array.

Comment: sorry mate, but when try to display it on view.blade it still seeing all array at once for each row. But when check the database. it proper inserting. How can it possible?

Comment: well, your initial issue of inserting is fixed. I think it's better that you post another question for the retrieval to avoid confusion on future readers.